# Использование регистровых переменных сравнения в циклах Си

Tags: c, оптимизация, производительность

Все источники утверждают, что в циклах использование регистровых переменных очень хорошо для производительности. Для меня остаётся не до конца понятен вопрос как компилятор оптимизирует код в том месте, где происходит сравнение индексной переменной i с переменой length.

```
double array[100ULL];

size_t length = 20ULL;

for(register size_t i = 0ULL; i < length - 1ULL; i++){
    array[i] = (double)i;
}
```

В этом примере индексная переменная i - регистровая. Но сравнение внутри for происходит с переменной length, которая НЕ объявлена как регистровая. Помимо прочего перед сравнением происходит математическая операция.

Хочу для себя прояснить пару-тройку моментов:

1. Будет ли откомпиллированная программа при каждой итерации цикла
   производить эту математическую операцию (вычитание единицы из
   меременной length) раз за разом или эта операция будет произведена
   только один раз перед началом цикла?
2. Догадается ли компилятор оптимизировать переменную length в
   регстровую?
3. Какой код будет правильнее с точки зрения производительности и
   однозначности для компилятора: тот, что выше, или нижеприведённый?
   И есть ли вообще разница для современных компиляторов?

Второй вариант кода, в котором обе сравниваемые переменные регистровые и операция вычитания однозначно производится перед циклом:

```
double array[100ULL];

register const size_t length = 10ULL - 1ULL;

for(register size_t i = 0ULL; i < length; i++){
    array[i] = (double)i;
}
```

Трансляция кода в asm ситуацию не прояснила, поэтому задаю напрямую.

Comment: Ответ будет различаться для разных компиляторов и даже для разных опций компиляции. В целом же: примерно с начала 90-х годов ручная оптимизация кода не имеет никакого смысла, компилятор всё равно сделает лучше и сделает по своему. Ключевое слово `register` сейчас не влияет ни на что.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Забудьте об этом слове `register`, оно давно не имеет никакого смысла.

Ответы на вопросы 1-2 зависят от компилятора; наверное, можно найти старый тупой компилятор, который не сумеет выполнить такие простые оптимизации.. А разумный - вообще может использовать какие-нибудь векторные команды процессора или что еще.

Так что ответ на вопрос 3 - нет, такой простой цикл будет оптимизирован любым более-менее разумным компилятором.

Кстати, VC++2017 просто развернул этот цикл в

```
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
cvtsi2sd xmm1, rbx
movsd   QWORD PTR array$[rsp], xmm1
xorps   xmm1, xmm1
cvtsi2sd xmm1, rax
mov eax, 2
cvtsi2sd xmm2, rax
mov eax, 3

.....

movsd   QWORD PTR array$[rsp+128], xmm2
movsd   QWORD PTR array$[rsp+136], xmm1
xorps   xmm1, xmm1
cvtsi2sd xmm1, rax
movsd   QWORD PTR array$[rsp+144], xmm1
```

ругнувшись при этом на слово `register` как давно не поддерживаемое... Результат видите сами.

Очень старенький OpenWatcom пошел по циклическому пути -

```
L$1:
    cmp         eax,13H 
    jae         L$2 
    mov         dword ptr 320H[esp],eax 
    xor         ecx,ecx 
    add         edx,8 
    mov         dword ptr 324H[esp],ecx 
    inc         eax 
    fild        qword ptr 320H[esp] 
    fstp        qword ptr -8[esp+edx] 
    jmp         L$1
```

но, как видите, вычислив 19 сразу, и работая только с регистрами...

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы и полезную информацию!

Answer (score 3):

gcc 6 сосчитал при компиляции и использовал сравнение счётчика с константой:

```
for(register size_t i = 0ULL; i < length - 1ULL; i++){                                                                       
 583:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax                                                                               
int main (void) {                                                                                                            
 585:   53                      push   rbx                                                                                   
 586:   48 81 ec 20 03 00 00    sub    rsp,0x320                                                                             
 58d:   48 89 e3                mov    rbx,rsp                                                                               
    array[i] = (double)i;                                                                                                    
 590:   66 0f ef c0             pxor   xmm0,xmm0                                                                             
 594:   f2 48 0f 2a c0          cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax                                                                            
 599:   f2 0f 11 04 c3          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbx+rax*8],xmm0                                                            
for(register size_t i = 0ULL; i < length - 1ULL; i++){                                                                       
 59e:   48 83 c0 01             add    rax,0x1                                                                               
 5a2:   48 83 f8 13             cmp    rax,0x13                                                                              
 5a6:   75 e8                   jne    590 <main+0x10>                                                                       
 5a8:   4c 8d a3 98 00 00 00    lea    r12,[rbx+0x98]                                                                        
}
```

**Ровно** то же самое он выдал без объявления i как register.

Answer (score 1):

Не надейтесь на компилятор, а оптимизируйте сами. Меньше пользуйтесь глобальными переменными. Самый популярный цикл в коде:

```
double array[100ULL];
size_t length = 20ULL;
for(size_t i = 0ULL; i < length - 1ULL; i++){
    array[i] = (double)i;}
```

пользуется глобальной переменной **lenght**. Этот доступ вы можете сами убрать лично:

```
double array[100ULL];
size_t length = 20ULL;
for(size_t i = length; i > 0; ){
  -- i ;
  array[i] = (double)i;}
```

В этом цикле будет только быстрая проверка на ноль. Уже быстрее. Дальше постоянно используется массив **array** с индексацией (сложение указателя с числом умноженный на размер double). Этот лишний код все убирают используя цикл по указателю.

```
double array[100ULL];
size_t length = 20ULL;
double * arrayj = &(array[length]) ;
for(size_t i = length; i > 0; ){
  -- i ;
  -- arrayj ;
  (*arrayj) = (double)i;}
```

В данном цикле используется только вычитание и сравнение с нулём. Попробуйте все примеры переносить в ассемблер и сравнить коды. Тогда вы поймёте кто плохо оптимизирует программы : компилятор или вы.

Comment: Большое спасибо полезную информацию!

Comment: Вы не поверите, но компиляторы и так делают копию глобальной переменной. Собственно из-за этого и существует ключевое слово `volatile`. Хуже того, при `-O2` «оптимизированный» код даёт значительно больше машинных инструкций из-за сложного цикла ([исходный вариант](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SSrH3R) — 18 строк, [вариант с ручным копированием](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NGCj33) — 31 строка). То есть своей оптимизацией вы только вставили компилятору палки в колёса. // cc: @DennisV.R.

Comment: @Arhad Что-то в длинном вашем варианте уже два цикла. Второй что-то складывает. Посмотрю сам.

Comment: Кстати, последний вариант, из которого «убрано всё лишнее», [также](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e5TS5k) дал 31 инструкцию. Так что не стоит считать, что компилятор не умеет анализировать и оптимизировать — в большинстве случаев это не так, особенно если включить *компиляцию времени компоновки* и оптимизацию не ниже второго уровня. Да, древние компиляторы были наивными, но уже достаточно давно они способны на достаточно сложные оптимизации, в которых человек иногда даже может запутаться.

Comment: `Что-то в длинном вашем варианте уже два цикла` — где? `.L11`-`.L5` — это пролог цикла, `.L5`-`.L1` — его тело. Разбиение `rax` (`i`) на `rdx` (`i / 2`) и `ecx` (признак нечётности) и их сложение (о котором вы спросили) — это [защита от двойного округления при преобразовании из `unsigned` в `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26799227/2553424) (сравните ассемблер по ссылке с тем, что получилось у вас (`and` + `shr` + `or` + `add`)).

Comment: Почему так вышло? Думаю, в наивном цикле компилятор смог доказать полное отсутствие ошибок округления и опустить все страхующие преобразования, а в «оптимизированном» коде он увидел какой-то граничный случай.

Comment: @Arhad нежданчик вышел с g++. Всё всегда было хорошо , а с double округлением не ожидал.

Comment: А Кнут говорил, что оптимизировать преждевременно - большое зло! Дайте сначала поработать компилятору.